# Typescript: Declaration Merging declare variable as interface

Tags: typescript

I have a class and an interface that have the same name. For example see code below:

```js
export interface option {
    name: string;
    tip: string;
}

export class option {
    constructor() {
    };

    someMethod(){};
}
```

First I want to construct by hand an option.

```js
export const test:option = 
{
    name:"hello",
    tip:"hi",
}
```

But I get `Property 'someMethod' is missing in type '{ name: string; tip: string; }' but required in type 'option'` In this particular case, I don't want to add the method, because later in the developpment it will be a parsed JSON.
I plan to create a `new option()` and the use `Object.assign()` to combine the data and the methods.

Is there an explicit way to tell the compiler I want to use the interface definition of `option` and not the class definition in this case? Of course, I would like to keep the TS checking for the `export const test:option...`

Comment: You can't: you will need to give them separate names. There are several naming conventions out there: for example, you can use the `I` prefix for interface names, i.e. `export interface IOption`, and then use `export class Option` (personally, I prefer using PascalCase for types).

Comment: That's what to expect when overriding names. The interface doesn't exist anymore

Comment: @Terry thanks, is there a way to avoid the copy of all the properties from the Interface into the Class?

Comment: @Victor You're not copying anything over: you are reassigning `option` to be a class instead of an interface.

Comment: @Terry sorry I wasn't clear. 
Is there a way to avoid the property duplication in the class? I mean I would have to add `name: string; tip: string;` to the class as well. This is fine for a small number of properties, but can be a bit difficult to maintain with large properties sets.

Comment: Do you mean you want to use `export class Option implements IOption`? Then, `IOption` will declare the types for class members, and `Option` class will be responsible for the declaration of class members itself: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQHkwYEIk4BvAKDjriUwFtgAuOAZximQHMBuWvVJh2XHkgHUAvtWqhIsONgA2mDhzjFS5REzArgLFJqIkyFGvWXlxAV2wxoACgCUVOLKF1GLOAF44AHIAMQgIACNMKCDBaxEA4IAZaCNEMA47Jli5aw4IFgBZYBgACwgAEzdKaUFpIA

Comment: It is exactly that. Thank you! Do you want to answer or should I?